# Split a string based on character using BASH variable parameters

Tags: string, bash

Suppose I have a strings which consist of sequences of commands:

`s1="c1|c2|c3>c4"`

`s2="c1>c2|c3|c4"`

I want to split these strings into two strings. The first string will be the first command `c1`. The second string will be the remaining commands (and pipes and redirects).

I can easily get the first command:

`echo ${s1%%[>|]*}
c1`

`echo ${s2%%[>|]*}
c1`

But getting the second string isn't so straightforward:

What I get:

`echo ${s1#*[>|]}
c2|c3>c4
echo ${s2#*[>|]}
c2|c3>c4`

What I want:

```
|c2|c3>c4

>c2|c3>c4
```

To summarize, if I have a compound command, where one command is piped or redirected to other commands, I want to split off the first command into one string, and the remaining commands into another string. including all pipes and redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the "c1" part in a variable, then, from the start of the original string, remove the captured text:

```
$ cmd=${s1%%[>|]*}; echo "$cmd"; echo "${s1#"$cmd"}"
c1
|c2|c3>c4

$ cmd=${s2%%[>|]*}; echo "$cmd"; echo "${s2#"$cmd"}"
c1
>c2|c3|c4
```

This even works when the string contains glob characters:

```
$ s2="c1*>c2|c3|c4"
$ cmd=${s2%%[>|]*}; echo "$cmd"; echo "${s2#"$cmd"}"
c1*
>c2|c3|c4
```